# Verification of a delta/epsilon Proof of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

So I am asked to show that $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is strictly increasing and $f^{-1}: f(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous at $1$.  My $f(x)$ is a point wise function 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x-1, & \textrm{ if } x<0 \\ x+1, & \textrm{ if } x\geq 0\end{cases}$$

Here's what I have so far:

To show strictly increasing, pick any two reals $a$ and $ b$ such that $a>b$.  If this is strictly increasing then $f(a)>f(b)$; I evaluate it to get $a-1>b-1$ and therefore $a>b$.

Likewise we can also pick any two reals $c$ and $d$ such that $c>d$.  If the function $f(x)=x+1$ is strictly increasing then $f(c)>f(d)$ must be true.  I evaluate it to get $c+1>d+1$ and so $c>d$.

Now to show the inverse is continuous at $1$ we use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition: $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $1$ provided that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all real $x$ values $|x-1|<\epsilon$ if $|x-1|<\delta$.

So assume $|x-1|<\delta$.  Let $\delta =\epsilon/2$,  which means $|x-1|<\epsilon/2<\epsilon$.  So it is continuous at $1$.  Is this correct?  If not, what needs to be changed?

Is this the right way to prove epsilon delta correctly and how should I change up this proof (including the first part) if needed?

Comment: check, the strictly increasing part. When you choose $a,b$ here you assumed that they were both less than zero since you evaluated then on $x-1$.

Answer (score 1):

I think much of what you need is essentially contained in what you wrote, but there are several technical inaccuracies; some cases are missing, and it looks like several of your implications are backwards (though I think it see what you intend).

So let's go through it carefully.

To show $f$ is strictly increasing, suppose $a<b$; we must show $f(a)<f(b)$. There are three cases to consider

**Case 1:** $a<0$ and $b<0$. In this case, $f(a)=a-1$ and $f(b)=b-1$; since $a<b$ implies $a-1<b-1$, we have that $f(a) = a-1<b-1=f(b)$ as required.

**Case 2:** $a<0$ and $b\geq 0$. In this case, $f(a)=a-1$ and $f(b)=b+1$; since $a<b$ implies $a-1<b-1$, and since $b -1< b +1$, we have that $f(a) = a-1<b-1<b+1=f(b)$ as required.

**Case 3:** $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$. In this case, $f(a)=a+1$ and $f(b)=b+1$; since $a<b$ implies $a+1<b+1$, we have that $f(a) = a+1<b+1=f(b)$ as required.

To show that the inverse is continuous at $1$, note that the domain of the inverse is $f(\mathbb R ) =(-\infty,-1)\cup[1,\infty)$, and on this domain we can write the inverse $f^{-1}$ as

$$f^{-1}(y) = \begin{cases} y+1, & \textrm{ if } y<-1 \\
y-1, & \textrm{ if } y\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$

Since $y$ can only approach $ 1$ from the right in the domain of $f^{-1}$, and the "pieces" that make up $f^{-1}$ are continuous (being the restrictions of linear functions), $f^{-1}$ is continuous.